# How to automatically insert my new userId in all table related?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

i have 4 tables 
Customer table
Department table 
shopping Table
planning Table
my question is :once i register the new user i want the same ID i to nsert inside all the tablse so that i can easily left join or etc with it 
i had a look at foreign key but it does not do the job 
im using mvc ( went from empty mvc using entity framework)
any help will be welcome.

Comment: Have you looked into using a trigger?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnHC and not not yet 
 i only created a table so far 
do i write the trigger inside my sql query or inside mvc ?

Answer (score 1):

you really need to look into EF first, and maybe include some code to your question. As far as I anderstood, you want something like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
  var user = new User(){Name = "test", ....};
  context.User.Add(user);
  context.SaveChanges();

  int id = user.Id; //you get the id after the insert in the db

 // here you can create new Customer, Department, Shopping Objects and insert it with the user id
}
```

Comment: thanks but i only created the table havn't start anything on mvc yet 
that why i asked the question before start coding .

Comment: whats your question then? How to add a foreign key to a sql table?

Comment: question is: what is the best ways to insert my new register clients ID 
into all other table ?
so that in the future when i wish to do retrieve all the info  about user i can do a left join on client ID